# Connecting Android Studio to Github is not working

Tags: android-studio, github

My android studio version is 2020.3.1, and my git version is 2.25.1.

I have a project open in android studio currently, and when I try to connect it to github, it doesn't work. I start in android studio and open files>settings>version control>Github> add an account. When I click add an account, it takes me to a jetbrains page asking me to authorize github. This is when the site glitches and asks me to log in to a 127.0.0.1 IP address. I think this error was caused when I tried it the first time; it was working then but once I was signing into github my firefox browser froze, and I haven't been able to get it to work since. Every time I try signing in to this 127.0.0.1 IP address, it doesn't work and eventually leads me to a 401 unauthorized page. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here are some pictures:

[The first page, asking me to log into a 127.0.0.1 IP address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3eeI.png)

[The 401 unauthorized page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWwbv.png)

(This is my first time using stackoverflow, so you'll have to click these links to view my pictures. Sorry for the inconvenience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to solve this problem:

1. Try to Login with Token. Top right corner of the login window you will find 'Use Token', switch to that.
2. After that generate a token by clicking on 'Generate' button and follow the link.
3. After generating token from gitHub site, copy that token and paste it on android studio login window.
4. Enjoy !

Comment: HI Tarique, that solved it thanks! I'm now able to get into my account and start working finally. Appreciate it.